# Approximate Indirect Diffuse

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, glsles

Im working on implementing indirect diffuse in my renderer and Im looking at section 8.4.1 [of this paper from Valve](http://www.valvesoftware.com/publications/2006/SIGGRAPH06_Course_ShadingInValvesSourceEngine.pdf).

In my renderer Im having a voxel grid of 256x256x256 with radiance and shadow injected and Im trying to convert/use this snippet from the paper to calculate ambient lighting against my voxels:

```
float3 AmbientLight( const float3 worldNormal )
{
  float3 nSquared = worldNormal * worldNormal;
  int3 isNegative = ( worldNormal < 0.0 );
  float3 linearColor;
  linearColor = nSquared.x * cAmbientCube[isNegative.x]   +
                nSquared.y * cAmbientCube[isNegative.y+2] +
                nSquared.z * cAmbientCube[isNegative.z+4];
  return linearColor;
}
```

The problem is that cannot figure out what is cAmbientCube in the calculation...

What is this variable and where it come from?

Comment: Looks like an array of 6 colors, no ?

Comment: Are you using desktop OpenGL or OpenGL ES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 8.4.1 section of the paper, where you copied the code from, pretty much explains it. `cAmbientCube` is an array of six light values, one for each principal direction: negative x, positive x, negative y, positive y, negative z, positive z. Whereas typical ambient term is assumed to be a constant light that illuminates from all directions, the Ambient Cube technique described in the paper is a generalization of this which assumes a different light coming from each of those directions. The code you posted is responsible for sampling from this ad-hoc six-sided cube-map texture.

Comment: So basically its just 6 values that "fake" a cubemap and the code above simply sample from them right? How theses 6 values are calculated? using spherical harmonics?

Comment: @McBob: Yes. The paper doesn't mention how to calculate them. To calculate it, I don't think spherical harmonics are appropriate here. Instead you should convolve each face of the environmental map with something like *x² + y² +z²* kernel, or simply average each of its faces. Alternatively those values might be manually chosen by the artist.